# "'str' object is not callable" when try to run input function in google colaboratory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

i was try to run this code and i did'nt find any problem with my code, but the google colaboratory called it error

this is the code :

```
start = int(input("Start : "))
end = int(input("End :"))
for i in range (start, end+1):
  print(i)
```

the error message :

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-bc333f731d78> in <module>()
----> 1 start = int(input("Start : "))
      2 end = int(input("End :"))
      3 for i in range (start, end+1):
      4   print(i)

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess, at some point in you code, you did:

```
int = "..."
```

or:

```
input = "..."
```

thus replacing the builtin function

Comment: thanks for answering, i already changed the variable, but sometimes google colab still called it error. is it effective restart the runtime to solve the problem? sorry for my bad english

Comment: @user16838812 then please update your question with the full code and full traceback

Comment: the code is already run normally, thanks for the help and i'm sorry for the late respond